# Wordpress polylang contact form 7 reCAPTCHA different languages

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7, polylang

I am using polylang to translate my wordpress site, it is in Japanese and english. The forms are built with contact form 7.

I found a some code to change the reCAPTCHA language from english to Japanese using the code below:

```
function wptricks24_recaptcha_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'google-recaptcha' );

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    $url = add_query_arg( array(
        'onload' => 'recaptchaCallback',
        'render' => 'explicit',
        'hl' => 'ja'), $url ); // es is the language code for Spanish language

    wp_register_script( 'google-recaptcha', $url, array(), '2.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts', 'wptricks24_recaptcha_scripts', 11 );
```

This makes all my forms display the reCAPTCHA in Japanese, is there a way I can make the reCAPTCHA on the english pages display in English and Japanese on the Japanese pages?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're just setting it to japanese all the time. To get current language locale from Polyland, use [`pll_current_language()`](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference#pll_current_language)

```
function wptricks24_recaptcha_scripts()
{
    wp_deregister_script('google-recaptcha');

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    $url = add_query_arg(array(
        'onload' => 'recaptchaCallback',
        'render' => 'explicit',
        'hl' => pll_current_language('slug')), $url);
    wp_register_script('google-recaptcha', $url, array(), '2.0', true);
}

add_action('wpcf7_enqueue_scripts', 'wptricks24_recaptcha_scripts', 11);
```